# Creating a new theme for Codename One

Tags: java, codenameone

How can I create a new theme for Codename One (one that could be seen in the Theme editor)? For example can I export one of the existing themes (to use it as a template), edit all its images in Photoshop and then load it as a new theme? I know that editing individual images is straightforward but if I could get at all the images at once it would make things considerably easier. Is that possible?

Comment: I edited your question to include the important comment under the only answer here. If you forget to include important info in your question initially, be sure to [edit] it in as soon as you find out. The same applies to clarifying the question. Otherwise you risk closure – your question is already attracting close votes. Hope I intervened on time.

Answer (score 1):

You can see the existing themes in SVN under the Themes directory: https://code.google.com/p/codenameone/source/browse/trunk/ you can just open such a theme and save it on top of the existing theme or import it into your theme. You can also use the + button to add a new theme.

Editing the whole theme in Photoshop isn't practical since Photoshop doesn't have that ability. A theme is more like CSS than an image. You can however edit the individual images that comprise the theme in photoshop by navigating to the image and clicking the edit button within the image area. This should launch the default application (e.g. photoshop) for editing the image type.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think I may have mis written the question. I wanted to be able to edit all the underlying images in a theme in a convenient way. I Saw that editing individual images is straightforward but if I could get at all the images at one it would make things considerably easier. Is that possible?

Comment: The images are inherently separate since they have very different resolutions (I'm assuming you are talking about multi images). You can work with the images directly under the res directory when the designer is closed, then just open the designer and save it to update the res file. I'm unsure how we can further improve on that experience.